# What is the meaning of "such orders as" in this text?

Tags: meaning, such

> Early in A.D.363 he addressed a letter to the Armenian monarch, requiring him to levy a considerable force, and hold himself in readiness to execute **such orders as** he would receive within a short time.
>
> — [*History of the Sasanian Empire: The Annals of the New Persian Empire*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FIhjDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT137&lpg=PT137&dq=Early+in+A.D.363+he+addressed+a+letter+to+the+Armenian+monarch,+requiring+him+to+levy+a+considerable+force,+and+hold+himself+in+readiness+to+execute+such+orders+as+he+would+receive+within+a+short+time.&source=bl&ots=LAeeX5uSZV&sig=ACfU3U2e97bNVRHQOtsFXfstrm4pAl0pog&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN8-_zmrvpAhUKSxUIHeE6CM4Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Early%20in%20A.D.363%20he%20addressed%20a%20letter%20to%20the%20Armenian%20monarch%2C%20requiring%20him%20to%20levy%20a%20considerable%20force%2C%20and%20hold%20himself%20in%20readiness%20to%20execute%20such%20orders%20as%20he%20would%20receive%20within%20a%20short%20time.&f=false), George Rawlinson, pub. e-artnow 2018

What does "such orders as" mean here?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What did your research tell you? For instance, see [sense 2 in Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/such): "to execute such orders as he would receive" — "carry out any orders that he would receive".

Comment: The Lexico definition gives the sense of 'such as' =  'of the type about to be mentioned'. But this is not the meaning here; the sense must be 'such Xs as' = 'all the Xs that'.

Comment: "such" is kind of like a adjective pronoun here if that makes sense.

Answer (score -4):

It's not too easy to find this sense of 'such N/s as [there are/were // he would receive // might occur ...]

[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/such) gives:

> - ... 5. **such as** ...
>
>   c. of the (usually small) amount, etc[, that there is / was ...]:
> - *The food, such as there was, was excellent*.

So 'to execute such orders as he would receive' means simply 'to execute whatever orders he received / would receive'. This particular example, unlike that provided by Collins, is a formal usage, probably only met with in legal circles nowadays.